# Radio Toggles not functioning correctly & unable to detect whole numbers and exit a while loop

Tags: autoit

I've tried to make a simple autoit script however I am having problems with the radio toggles not working correctly and unable to detect whole numbers.

#### Code:

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <GUIListBox.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Local $InputListItems[3] = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]
Local $test[1] = ["dog"]
Local $test1[1] = ["cat"]

$Form1 = GUICreate("Form1", 651, 250, 192, 124)

$InputMain = GUICtrlCreateGroup("Input Main", 8, 0, 137, 137)

$InputListMain = GUICtrlCreateList("", 16, 16, 121, 118)
GUICtrlSetData($InputListMain, _ArrayToString($InputListItems))

$InputAlt = GUICtrlCreateGroup("Input Alt", 151, 0, 137, 137)

$InputListAlt = GUICtrlCreateList("", 159, 16, 121, 118)
GUICtrlSetData($InputListAlt, _ArrayToString($InputListItems))

$Rates = GUICtrlCreateGroup("Rates", 6, 139, 281, 49)
$MainRateInput = GUICtrlCreateInput("1", 14, 155, 121, 21)
$AltRateInput = GUICtrlCreateInput("3", 158, 155, 121, 21)

$LeftOutputs = GUICtrlCreateGroup("Left Option", 296, 0, 169, 185)
$LeftOutputList = GUICtrlCreateList("", 304, 16, 153, 162)
GUICtrlSetData($LeftOutputList, _ArrayToString($test))

$RightOutputs = GUICtrlCreateGroup("Right Option", 472, 0, 169, 185)
$RightOutputList = GUICtrlCreateList("", 480, 16, 153, 162)
GUICtrlSetData($RightOutputList, _ArrayToString($test1))

$Output = GUICtrlCreateGroup("Main Output", 8, 192, 281, 49)
$OututInput = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 16, 208, 265, 21)

$Picker = GUICtrlCreateGroup("Option", 294, 192, 345, 49)
$Radio1 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("Left", 312, 216, 113, 17)
$Radio2 = GUICtrlCreateRadio("Right", 488, 216, 113, 17)

GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
;GUICtrlSetState($Radio1, $GUI_CHECKED)

Func GenerateRates($MainRate, $AltRate)

    Local $Start = $MainRate
    Local $End = $AltRate
    Local $PossibleValues[0] = []
    Local $FloatTrigger = False

    Local $PossibleValue = $Start & "/" & $End
    _ArrayAdd($PossibleValues, $PossibleValue)
    For $i = 1 To 29
        $Start = $Start
        $End = $End + 0.1
        ;If StringInStr(".", String($End)) Then
        ;   ConsoleWrite($Start & @CRLF)
        ;   $End = $End * 10
        ;   $Start = $Start * 10
        ;EndIf
        If IsInt(Number($End)) Then ; IsInt($End) <> $End  ;Mod($End, 1) = 0 ;IsInt(Number($End))
            $FloatTrigger = True
            $StartEx = $Start
            $EndEx = $End
        Else
            $FloatTrigger = False
        EndIf

        While $FloatTrigger = True
            $StartEx = $StartEx + $MainRate
            $EndEx = $EndEx + $AltRate + 0.1
            ConsoleWrite($StartEx & @CRLF)
            ConsoleWrite($EndEx & @CRLF)
            Sleep(500)
            If IsInt(Number($EndEx)) Then ; IsInt($EndEx) <> $End  ;Mod($EndEx, 1) = 0 ;IsInt(Number($EndEx))
                $FloatTrigger = True
            Else
                $FloatTrigger = False
            EndIf
        WEnd
        If $FloatTrigger = True Then
            $PossibleValue = $StartEx & "/" & $EndEx
        Else
            $PossibleValue = $Start & "/" & $End
        EndIf
        _ArrayAdd($PossibleValues, $PossibleValue)
    Next
    _ArrayDisplay($PossibleValues, "")
EndFunc   ;==>GenerateRates

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
        Case $nMsg = $Radio1 = $GUI_CHECKED
            If GUICtrlRead($OututInput) <> GUICtrlRead($LeftOutputList) Then
                GUICtrlSetData($OututInput, GUICtrlRead($LeftOutputList))
            EndIf
        Case $nMsg = $Radio2 = $GUI_CHECKED
            If GUICtrlRead($OututInput) <> GUICtrlRead($RightOutputList) Then
                GUICtrlSetData($OututInput, GUICtrlRead($RightOutputList))
            EndIf
        ; Working Start
        Case $nMsg = $InputListMain
            GUICtrlSetData($Radio1, "Left: " & GUICtrlRead($InputListMain))
        Case $nMsg = $InputListAlt
            GUICtrlSetData($Radio2, "Right: " & GUICtrlRead($InputListAlt))
        ; Working End
        Case $nMsg = $MainRateInput
            If GUICtrlRead($Radio1) = 1 Then
                GenerateRates(GUICtrlRead($MainRateInput), GUICtrlRead($AltRateInput))
            Else
                GenerateRates(GUICtrlRead($AltRateInput), GUICtrlRead($MainRateInput))
            EndIf
        Case $nMsg = $AltRateInput
            If GUICtrlRead($Radio1) = 1 Then
                GenerateRates(GUICtrlRead($MainRateInput), GUICtrlRead($AltRateInput))
            Else
                GenerateRates(GUICtrlRead($AltRateInput), GUICtrlRead($MainRateInput))
            EndIf
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

#### Problem 1:

- Normally checking to see if a number is a whole number is fairly easy, you can usually use: `IsInt(Number($value))` or `Mod($value, 1) = 0` however in my script it's not working at all.

#### Problem 2:

- The radio buttons aren't working, if I chose the left option and right options of "cat" and "dog" and then chose the radio button's associated with each side, the "dog" one (left) puts "dog" into the output box but the "cat" one (right) doesn't put "cat" into the output box...

I've tried tons of different ways of writing the case, including: `Case $nMsg = GUICtrlRead($Radio1) = $GUI_CHECKED` and `Case $nMsg = $Radio1 And BitAND(GUICtrlRead($Radio1), $GUI_CHECKED) = $GUI_CHECKED`

#### Re: Interger testing...

I've tried everything I know about to test the value including: `ConsoleWrite(_WinAPI_FloatToInt($End) & @CRLF)` to see if that helps, it doesn't. They all appear to be floats even though some numbers appear whole numbers (5) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your while statement that deals with the GUI events has issues, because a statement like

Case $nMsg = $Radio1 = $GUI_CHECKED

seems to be interpreted as

Case $nMsg

Hence, just the first such statement will be triggered (since we must have that $nMsg==$nMsg). The only reason your program exited successfully is that the code for that was the first block in your switch statement. The fix is very easy, the GUI code for $Radio1 is just $Radio1

```
While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
        Case $Radio1
            If GUICtrlRead($OututInput) <> GUICtrlRead($LeftOutputList) Then
                GUICtrlSetData($OututInput, GUICtrlRead($LeftOutputList))
            EndIf
        Case $Radio2
            If GUICtrlRead($OututInput) <> GUICtrlRead($RightOutputList) Then
                GUICtrlSetData($OututInput, GUICtrlRead($RightOutputList))
            EndIf
        ; Working Start
        Case $InputListMain
            GUICtrlSetData($Radio1, "Left: " & GUICtrlRead($InputListMain))
        Case $InputListAlt
            GUICtrlSetData($Radio2, "Right: " & GUICtrlRead($InputListAlt))
        ; Working End
        Case $MainRateInput
            If GUICtrlRead($Radio1) = 1 Then
                GenerateRates(GUICtrlRead($MainRateInput), GUICtrlRead($AltRateInput))
            Else
                GenerateRates(GUICtrlRead($AltRateInput), GUICtrlRead($MainRateInput))
            EndIf
        Case $AltRateInput
            If GUICtrlRead($Radio1) = 1 Then
                GenerateRates(GUICtrlRead($MainRateInput), GUICtrlRead($AltRateInput))
            Else
                GenerateRates(GUICtrlRead($AltRateInput), GUICtrlRead($MainRateInput))
            EndIf
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Your issues with integer testing probably come down to floating point rounding. However, as your code is currently written, if $FloatTrigger is ever set to true, you'll end up in an infinite while loop

Comment: One comment: The radio control can have a combined state. If you compare with "1", you may not have a hit even though the control is checked. That's why it's recommended to check with BitAnd: `If BitAnd(GUICtrlRead($Radio), $GUI_CHECKED) Then ; radio is checked`